# Get a array from $app->get Slim Framework

Tags: php, frameworks, slim

I have some problem with my app Slim Framework
I would get the title of the recovered sample here

```
$app->get('/', function() use ($app){
$app->render('pages/homepage.php', array(
    'title' => 'Homepage',
));});
```

For example diferent pages also
and it does not work

homepage.php return MySiteName | Home in  html
wiki.php return MySiteName | Wiki in  html

Comment: Would you share the content of your `homepage.php`?

Comment: Your question in not so clear. Can you improve it?